# AngularJS query parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a small search app using UI Router that looks like this:

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('searchApp.routes', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $stateProvider
           .state('home', {
            url: '/home',           
            templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
            controller: 'SearchCtrl'})         
          .state('search', {            
            templateUrl: 'search/search.html',
            url: '/search?q',           
            controller: 'SearchCtrl'
          });    
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
}]);
```

So as you can see two (2) states, two(2) templates and one(1) controller. What is NOT WORKING CORRECTLY is that from the home state to the search state, the search functionality requires 2 submissions for results to display and the same is required on the search state if the user wants to enter a different query.

The query is displaying in the url as desired but then it takes another submission for the results to display...?

I initialize `$stateParams` like this in my `SearchCtrl`

```
$scope.searchTerms = $stateParams.q || '';
```

where searchTerms is my ng-model on the search form.

I have `$state.go()` setup like this in my `SearchCtrl` in the search function

```
$state.go('search', {q: $scope.searchTerms});
```

What am I missing and/or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  url: '/search?q',  to  url: '/search/:q' and try getting the value from $stateParams.q

```
 .state('search', {            
        templateUrl: 'search/search.html',
        url: '/search/:q',           
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and it just changes url from /search?=query to search/query. Results still require second submission. Any thoughts.

Comment: '/search/:query' that ':' is required. And read value from $stateParams.query

Comment: yes I used url: '/search/:q', and still got the result in my first comment

Comment: How does your URL looks like? It should be http://your_domain/search/your_search_string

Comment: Just for testing, could you add an 'a' tag with ui-sref="search({q: 'test'})" in home.html?

Comment: @user3125823 - are you getting the passed parameters value properly in this case?

Comment: yes the 'test' parameter is displaying in the url on the search page

Comment: No, I mean to ask whether you are getting value in $stateParams.q in this case

Comment: sorry, no, it just prints out the string if I replace 'test' with '$stateParams.q'

Comment: Oops..that was not I was looking for. 1. Have the anchor tag in home.html with ui-sref="search({q: 'test'})" 2. In search controller try getting the passed value using $stateParams.q

Comment: sorry, ok did it. the passed value is test

Comment: Does that mean, in your search controller you were able to get the passed value using $stateParams.q?

Comment: sorry, - got pulled away for a moment, yes I was able to get the passed value

Comment: nearly but I can handle it. Thank you for your efforts! I've accepted your answer - put me on the right track.

Comment: No probs..happy coding mate.